# Can I add "reboot" as a option to shutdown dialog?

Tags: shutdown, reboot, dialog

When I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> on Ubuntu I get this dialog. Reboot is not an option. How can I add it?

[image]

Comment: Look at keyboard shortcuts - possibly re-assign to your liking

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Delete is bound to "Log Out" but there doesn't seem to be a "Shutdown" or "Reboot" option. What I want is a dialog which contains all those options.